# How to push git from php using exec()

Tags: php, windows, git, batch-file, git-push

Here is my **push.bat** file

```
echo "Hello world!"
cd abhishek3/
call git add .
call git commit -m "sadf"
call heroku accounts:set abhishek84 
call git push heroku master
```

---

I am able to push to my repository by **running push.bat file in cmd**

I want to push to my repo from php, tried following snippets but none of them worked for me.

```
exec("psexec -d push.bat");
```

**Result:** **PHP page loads indefinitely**

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C abhishek3.bat, 0, false);
```

**Result: Page stops loading after a while and nothing works**

```
exec("cmd.exe /c abhishek3.bat")
```

**Result: Page stops loading after a while and nothing works**

**EDIT:**
Tried the following snippet but nothing worked.

```
exec("hstart.exe /NOCONSOLE \"cmd.exe /c \"abhishek3.bat\"\"");
```

The above snippet runs successfully when run from cmd but when run from php through exec() didn't worked. [Download hstart (Hidden Start Binary)](http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)

Comment: As you're saying "page loads" I assume you are testing via web server? did you try from php cli? Probably the webserver is running with other privilies tha your user and that stops it?

Comment: I am running the webserver from localhost. When I run php -r "$ret = exec('abhishek3.bat'); echo $ret;" from cmd it executes the batch file successfully. If I run it from webpage it doesn't performs the push..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check the permissions for the web users are correct (It can access the files and execute git)
2. check the path for git and any environment variables it may need. You may have to set those environment variables in your script and use absolute paths)
3. check IIS or apache (whichever you are using) is allowed to execute programs in general and bat files (for example if it is apache, you may have to configure httpd.conf or htaccess depending on your configuration)

Comment: git init runs successfully.. git commit runs successfully... git push doesn't runs when run through php web page (It runs when executed from PHP CLI..) What can be the cause of it ?

Comment: it looks like a firewall restriction. try (1) turning off iptables temporarily (2) turning off selinux temporarily.

Comment: I just remembered this is windows. Try turning off the firewall. This is also powershell, check executionpolicy and set it to unrestricted

Comment: Firewall was already disabled. Also I set the execution policy to unrestricted but git push heroku master didn't worked.

Comment: probably missing the SSH key / credentials/ known_hosts as a web user

Comment: If this would be the case then why I am able to call git push heroku master through PHP CLI ..

Comment: the web server does run as a separate user - generally as IIS_IUSR . PHP cli is run as your user (either admin or whatever you login is) the credentials are stored in your user directory so it works from command line but not in IIS_IUSR (or whatever the web user is) directory